# Find Location inside building or Malls

Tags: android, geolocation, gis

How to find indoor location without GPS?
There are many method to find indoor location such as Wifi triangulation,Cellular network,Fingerprint,Bluetooth  & Magnetic fields..ect.
- I have tried Wifi triangulation but for triangulation you need to know physical geolocation of min. two or three Access Point.I dont have any database or any physical location of WAP's... Is there in way/formula to find location of router without using google geolocation API's.
- How find location using Android Magnetic Field?

Please help me out...to find indoor location :(

Answer (score 0):

Google play service`FusedLocationApi` provides the accurate (claimed by Google) with the combination of GPS, Wifi and Cellular Network. You can use this for indoor/under buildings locations. For example please look http://www.adavis.info/2014/09/android-location-updates-with.html.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply I will try it and let you know...I have tried location manager class using network provider but location accuracy was 30-40m which is not useful.

Comment: Please let me know the results after you have completed your testing. thanks

Comment: Hi, have tried this for indoor application...because for indoor Wifi-triangulation and Geo-Magenatic compass are famous methods..

Comment: Hi,I have tried with FusedLocationApi and also compare with LocationManager. Both classes are giving me same result with accuracy 45.57(i have tested this inside the building- 8th floor).For indoor location this much accuracy will make huge difference. It will not work anyway thanks by that time let me know if you find some another solution....Thanks for help